# How do you open a webpage in Outlook 2007 with VBA and .OnAction?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a context menu so that when I right-click on someone's name it will query a webpage to bring back their rolodex information.  It is not kept in the local contacts.  I have it in a webpage.

I have this I found and have been using (snippet of larger sub),

```
 ' Configure the button to call the
        ' DisplayItemMetadata routine when
        ' clicked. The Parameter property of the
        ' button is set to the value of the
        ' EntryID property for the selected
        ' item, if possible.
        With objButton
            .Caption = "&Look Up Name"
            .FaceId = 1000
            .Tag = "DisplayItemMetadata"
            If Not IsNull(Selection.Item(1)) Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' Just in case the item selected
                ' doesn't have a valid EntryID.
                .Parameter = Selection.Item(1).EntryID
                On Error GoTo ErrRoutine
            End If
            '.OnAction = _
             '   "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.DisplayItemMetadata"
              .OnAction = _
                   "NavigateToURL(""http://somewebsite"")"
        End With
```

It never calls the NavigateToURL sub.  It never calls the function, so I can never get to the below code.  No errors.  Breakpoints and Debug show it simply ending the With and Sub.  I have tried using,

```
Call NavigateToURL(""http://somewebsite"")
NavigateToURL "http://somewebsite"
```

Neither work.  I get `Expected Expression`.

```
Public Sub NavigateToURL(ByVal argURL As String)
MsgBox ("hi")
  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

  Dim objIE As Object

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  With objIE
    .Visible = False
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate argURL
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With

  objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

If there is another way to open a webpage with a context menu?  Tooltip?

EDIT:  Sorry.  I had to find where I got it.  It is from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176426%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```
Sub Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay( _
    ByVal CommandBar As Office.CommandBar, _
    ByVal Selection As Selection)

    Dim objButton As Office.CommandBarButton

    On Error GoTo ErrRoutine

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        ' Add a new button to the bottom of the CommandBar
        ' (which represents the item context menu.)
        Set objButton = CommandBar.Controls.Add( _
            msoControlButton)

        ' Configure the button to call the
        ' DisplayItemMetadata routine when
        ' clicked. The Parameter property of the
        ' button is set to the value of the
        ' EntryID property for the selected
        ' item, if possible.
        With objButton
            .Caption = "&Display metadata"
            .FaceId = 1000
            .Tag = "DisplayItemMetadata"
            If Not IsNull(Selection.Item(1)) Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' Just in case the item selected
                ' doesn't have a valid EntryID.
                .Parameter = Selection.Item(1).EntryID
                On Error GoTo ErrRoutine
            End If
            .OnAction = _
                "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.DisplayItemMetadata"
        End With
    End If

EndRoutine:
    Exit Sub

ErrRoutine:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _
        "Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay"
    GoTo EndRoutine
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayItemMetadata()

    Dim objNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strEntryID As String

    On Error GoTo ErrRoutine

    ' Retrieve the value of the Parameter property from the
    ' control that called this routine.
    strEntryID = _
        Application.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter

    ' If there's no entry ID, we can't easily retrieve the item.
    If strEntryID = "" Then
        MsgBox "An entry ID could not be retrieved from " & _
            "the selected menu item."
    Else
        ' Fetch an item reference using the specified entry ID.
        Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objItem = objNamespace.GetItemFromID(strEntryID)

        If objItem Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "A reference for the Outlook item " & _
                "could not be retrieved."
        Else
            ' Display information about the item.
            MsgBox "Message Class: " & objItem.MessageClass & vbCrLf & _
                "Size:          " & objItem.Size
        End If
    End If

EndRoutine:
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objNamespace = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrRoutine:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _
        "DisplayItemMetadata"
    GoTo EndRoutine
End Sub
```

Comment: The example code you have commented out uses a different construct for naming the `OnAction` procedure: `Project1.ThisOutlookSession...`  Perhaps you are missing something?  Since the website doesn't appear to be dynamically changing, you may want to `Const` that within the `NavigateToURL` procedure, too, rather than sending it as an argument (which can be tricky I think since you have to string it).

Comment: How do I open a webpage at all with .onAction (or some other method)?

Comment: **The example code you have commented out uses a different construct for naming the OnAction procedure: Project1.ThisOutlookSession...**  Perhaps your code is incomplete?

Comment: @DavidZemens I read it the first time.  I promise.  I will read more on .OnAction, as I did not understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** *If you provide the code that creates the context menu, I'll gladly test this out, but I'm not going to be able to help much further unless you provide that code.*

What I am trying to say in comments above, is that you have specified an argument for `OnAction` that may not be recognized, and as such, no procedure is being called.

Based *only on the example syntax*, I assume that this needs a fully-qualified construct of the procedure name.  In the example syntax, it has:

`.OnAction = "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.SomeProcedure"`

But your code omits the Project and Session scope.

Something like `.OnAction = "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.NavigateToURL"` might work, then.

In the above, I would omit the URL as an argument, which requires you modify the procedure `NavigateToURL` slightly.  since the URL is not changing ever, it is silly to pass this as an argument to the procedure `NavigateToURL`.  Within the `NavigateToURL` procedure, simply declare this as a `Const` string.

```
Public Sub NavigateToURL()
Const argURL as String = "http://somewebsite.com"   '## Modify as needed
MsgBox ("hi")
  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

  Dim objIE As Object

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  With objIE
    .Visible = False
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate argURL
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With

  objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why it won't find the Sub, but I put it in the stock Sub from MsFt.  It did not work.  Just goes through the code.  I changed .Visible to True and an IE window just pops open for a second and dies.

Comment: well if IE pops open for a second then it clearly *does* find the sub and execute the code. I'm not familiar with the `.Silent` argument, maybe set that to `False` and make `.Visible = True`?